# Getting some Security issues with IIS

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, iis

My Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo theFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\Server_Attachments\6");
    string Attachment = "";
    foreach (FileInfo nextFile in theFolder.GetFiles())
    {
        Attachment += "<a href=\"C:\\temp\\Server_Attachments\\6\\blabla.xls\">" + nextFile.ToString() + "</a><br />";
        div1.InnerHtml = Attachment;
    }
}

protected void Attach_File(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"C:\Server_Attachments\6");
}
}
```

and my HTML page is like this

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Attach a file : "></asp:Label><br />

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" />
<br />

<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text=" Attach " Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-  Size="Small" OnClick="Attach_File" />
```

Neither the hyperlinks, neither the upload is working :(

- when I am clicking on the hyperlinks nothing is happening (although "Save target as" is working).
- when I am trying to upload, I have got the error "Access to the path 'C:\Server_Attachments\6' is denied."

It is obviously a security issue. I have checked which account was running the program and it is NETWORK SERVICE.

How do I fix this ? Can I give full access to NETWORK SERVICE? Is it secure?

Comment: NETWORK SERVICE will need to have read/write permission to the directory: `C:\Server_Attachments`. You could consider creating a new Windows account, giving that permission and then using that for the application, but that is up to you to decide

Comment: @zxc No, you don't. The user that needs write access, needs write access. Surely not everyone.

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time. Issue is resolved now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow file upload then that's what you have to do.  Yes, that's potentially a security issue - you need to make sure everything else is locked down.

Give "Write" access to "Network Service" for the upload folder. Give "Read" access to "Network Service" for the download folder.

no need to grant full control to Network Service.

Comment: How can I give only "Write" acces to "Network Service" without granting full control to Network Service ?

Comment: These links might be helpful for you.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/22383/how-to-give-read-write-permission-to-a-folder-and-its-sub-folders-and-files

http://superuser.com/questions/445279/allowing-only-a-specific-service-read-write-access-to-a-folder

http://serverfault.com/questions/490691/what-does-it-mean-to-grant-set-permissions-for-network-service-on-a-network-shar/490697

Comment: Similar to your given 1st linke, I have changed ownership of my localhost file on /var/www/ and its sub folders and given it permission 777. However, whenever I add a new folder in it the new folder does not automatically get that permission. How can I give a folder 777 permission forever so that if I add a new folder or file it gets the same permission?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting what you actually trying to accomplish.
but giving permission 777 is not a good idea. Have you gone through other links?

Comment: I've gone through the second link http://superuser.com/questions/445279/allowing-only-a-specific-service-read-write-access-to-a-folder

it's really helpful. I've resolved my Issue.

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time. Issue is resolved now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the permissions for the whole application and the resouces it can access.

Good practice would be to create a new user on the server, remove this from the users group and add it as a member of the IIS_IUSER group.

The folders the application accesses can now be given access t this user, it also good to create a database login for this user and map the applications database.

This way your application is isolated from other applications by permissions.

Comment: I would also add that you should abtract file system retreival from the front end, ie not accessing files directly and rather use an HttpHandler or similar: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2008/05/22/httphandler-to-authorize-file-downloads-c-code-sample.aspx

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time. Issue is resolved now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Give write access to the IIS_IUSER for that folder and try.

Comment: Thanks for giving your precious time. Issue is resolved now. :)